# Press effect on button doesnt seem to work

Tags: qt, qml, meego

//MainPage.qml

```
   Button{
        id: pushI
        text: qsTr("录音")
        //onClicked: label.visible = true
        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            MyItem { id: inputA}
            onPressed:
            {
                inputA.on_pressed()//my c++ class method
            }
            onReleased:
            {
                inputA.on_released()//my c++ class method
            }

        }
    }
```

the $onClicked$ property can do,but i have a press-release process,how to do?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what your problem is?

Comment: i want to have a click effect,but button always checkedable,sorry,my english is every bad so can't explain clear

Answer (score 0):

i'm slove

```
    Button{
        id: button
        state: "RELEASED"
        text: qsTr("录音")
        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            MyItem { id: inputA}
            onPressed:
            {
                inputA.on_pressed()
                button.state = "PRESSED"
            }
            onReleased:
            {
                inputA.on_released()
                button.state = "RELEASED"
            }
        }
        states: [
        State {
        name: "PRESSED"
        PropertyChanges { target: button; checked: true}
        },
        State {
        name: "RELEASED"
        PropertyChanges { target: button; checked: false}
        }
        ]
    }
```